# Calculate cost of credits

Tags: database, math, e-commerce

Consider an ecommerce site like istock, envato, etc.

Users can purchase items directly, or via pre-purchased credits which are sold at a discount (all relative to US dollar).

The credit discounts are variable, however. They can change based on quantity, strategy changes, coupons, there can be short-term sales, etc. For example, 25 credits might cost $22.50 (10% discount) while 100 credits might cost $75 (25% discount).

Assume we have a past history of all previous purchases so that the average cost of all credits is attainable by the following formula:

AverageCost = (p1.costPer * p1.numberBought) +  (pn.costPer * pn.numberBought) / (p1.numberBought + pn.numberBought)

**How can the spending history be used to calculate the current real value of credits in the user's account?**

If the user has *never bought any credits* before, or has *never spent any credits*, then the value of a credit is exactly AverageCost (as demonstrated above)

However - if they have spent some credits previously, and bought new credits - how does the previous spending shift the average value of current credits?

Use case is a revenue share, where revenue split must be calculated based on money value, even when paid via credits sold in this manner.

Therefore, it could very well be that another relevant variable is knowing what has already been paid out (and any data which comes along with that)

Comment: It sounds like you need a weighted average of credit prices, but it's not clear to me: sum(price*# credits)/sum(# credits)

Comment: updated, let me know if that clears it up for you

Comment: Clears it up for me?  You wrote the formula I put in my comment.  I think I cleared it up for you.  You need to think about prices in terms of time series or Markov chains or moving averages.  This is a common problem for calculating the value of a stock position.

Comment: Made several more changes than just copy/paste, including shifting the focus to specifically ask about impact of spending history - which you're hinting toward. Telling me it's a common problem doesn't really help much though, is there more data that's needed to construct a reliable formula for this?

Comment: Telling you it's a common problem is a gentle suggestion to do some research in addition to asking on SO.

Comment: If you don't know the answer you can just say so

Comment: I think the answer I gave is rather good.  It's far different from "not knowing".  Why is that average insufficient for you?  How would you change it?  Should older credits be weighted less than more recent ones?  (Markov chain)

Comment: You clearly know enough to ask intelligent questions, yet you are not providing a good answer in SO terms. This is a programming site, not a financial theory site. If you have pseudocode or formulas which take the given data and yield a reasonable result - I will gladly upvote/accept that. In SO terms, it is even better with explanation of how your formulas/pseudocode work and in what situations one might choose one vs. another.

Comment: I gave pseudocode and a formula that you were happy to copy as if you'd thought of it.  We'll see who can improve on it.

Comment: Actually I copied it word for word from an email exchange from a friend of mine who is not on stackoverflow (as far as I know or at least I don't know his handle to tag, Elyon if you see this feel free to mention and I'll tag you).

Yes, you both knew that finding the average solves some cases and I appreciate the help as I did not know that.

However, "how to average" is only part of the story. Pseoducode for a "markov chain" or "time series" or "moving average", which are all ideas you've suggested, could be thorough answers to the specific question. Guess we won't know...

Comment: To answer why the basic average doesn't work - let's say credits are bought at 25% discount, and then all spent and revenue is paid out. Now they buy new credits at 10% discount. Since all share has been paid against the past credits, the new split should be done only considering 10% discount, not the average based on past history. With that in mind - it seems to me that a missing variable is knowing what has been paid out, but I'm not sure. I do appreciate your questions as they are helping me come closer and closer to an answer, though a proper answer would simply include this, no?

Comment: I'm not interested.  I commented precisely because I didn't want a long discussion.  Please direct your comments to someone who answers.  One more thought: Why don't you be an experimentalist and try it?  You don't know.  I assume you have some data, real or simulated, that you could implement the simple idea on and elaborate on as new information came in.

Comment: Yes, I will experiment with any and all solutions I come across. Thanks